# Check if select contains a specific value

Tags: jquery, selection

I have a select with about 50 items, here's a small sample.
I want to check if the select contains a specific exact value, so when looking for 'Beauty', that would be 1 match and not 2.

I thought of looping through all items, but then I came across this:
http://api.jquery.com/is/

and thought that might perform better. I however, have no idea how to use it on this code:

```
<select id="mydropdown" class="textbox">
    <option value="Beauty">Beauty</option>
    <option value="Catering">Catering</option>
    <option value="Beautysalon">Beautysalon</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you trying to check if the `select` contains the `option` of Beauty, or checking if it's current value is Beauty?

Comment: If the selection contains the option 'Beauty', so I don't care whether it's selected yes or no.

Comment: Then use Joseph's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an attribute selector:

```
var hasBeauty = !! $('#mydropdown > option[value="Beauty"]').length;
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gLPJ5/

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#mydropdown').val() == "Beauty")
{
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a faster, modern solution that doesn't use `querySelector` or `jQuery`.
What it does, is it takes the `options` object, converts it to an array and uses `includes` to check for the value. All methods are part of the native JS api.

```js
function optionExists (select, value) {
  const options = Object.values(select.options).map(option => option.value)
  return options.includes(value)
}

const select = document.getElementById('mydropdown')
console.log(optionExists(select, 'Beauty'))
console.log(optionExists(select, 'Be'))
```

```html
<select id="mydropdown" class="textbox">
    <option value="Beauty">Beauty</option>
    <option value="Catering">Catering</option>
    <option value="Beautysalon">Beautysalon</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ES6 / vanilla** :

`(select, optionValue) => [...select.options].some((o) => o.value == optionValue);`